# Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Result<Void, Error>' that does not accept a closure. Google Sign In completion check

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin

I'd like to check that is login process is complete.

```
fileprivate var isLoggedIn: ((Result<Void,Error>) -> Void)
```

```
func signIn(viewController: UIViewController, complition: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let shared = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return }
        shared.scopes = [Constants.kScope]
        shared.presentingViewController = viewController
        shared.signIn()
        isLoggedIn { result in
            complition(.success((result)))
        }
```

when Im trying to do:

```
 isLoggedIn { result in
            complition(.success((result)))
        }
```

xcode says *Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Result<Void, Error>' that does not accept a closure*

Method from extension calling from `shared.signIn()`

```
extension GoogleAuthService: GIDSignInDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        guard error == nil else {
            isLoggedIn(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        guard user != nil else { return }
        isLoggedIn(.success(()))
        accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken
    }
}
```

Im new to Swift and have some issues with closure syntax. Is there better way to check completion of login method from GidSignInDelegate?
Help me, please :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea for converting a delegate based API into a closure based API; You need to store the completion handler in a property and then invoke it from the delegate methods.

You have declared the property `isLoggedIn` correctly, but you aren't assigning the completion handler to it, and you are trying to invoke it with a trailing closure in your `signIn` function.

I would suggest that you change your `Result` to `Result<GIDGoogleUser,Error>` - You may as well return the user in the success case.

```
fileprivate var isLoggedIn: ((Result<GIDGoogleUser,Error>) -> Void)?

func signIn(viewController: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Result<GIDGoogleUser, Error>) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let shared = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return false }
    shared.scopes = [Constants.kScope]
    shared.presentingViewController = viewController
    shared.delegate = self
    self.isLoggedIn = completion
    shared.signIn()
    return true
}

extension GoogleAuthService: GIDSignInDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        guard error == nil else {
            self.isLoggedIn?(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        guard user != nil else { return }
        self.isLoggedIn?(.success(user))
        accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken
    }
}
```

You can also define your own errors so that you can call the completion handler for the situations where you just silently return:

```
enum GoogleAuthServiceError: Error {
    case noAuthService
    case noUser
}


func signIn(viewController: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Result<GIDGoogleUser, Error>) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let shared = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { 
        completion(.error(GoogleAuthServiceError.noAuthService))
        return false 
    }
    shared.scopes = [Constants.kScope]
    shared.presentingViewController = viewController
    shared.delegate = self
    self.isLoggedIn = completion
    shared.signIn()
    return true
}

extension GoogleAuthService: GIDSignInDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        guard error == nil else {
            self.isLoggedIn?(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        guard user != nil else { 
            self.isLoggedIn?(.error(GoogleAuthServiceError.noUser))
            return 
        }

        self.isLoggedIn?(.success(user))
        accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken
    }
}
```